# software tool for accurate visualization of algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-software, algebraic-curves, visualization

First of all, I apologize since this is not strictly speaking a "mathematical" question but I could not find a better place for it.

For a work presentation I need a tool for accurate visualization of implicit 
algebraic curves in 2D. I tried ImplicitPlot function from Maple but for some complicated 
curves the results are not satisfiable. Also, it is not very convenient 
to zoom at certain locations along the curve.

I appreciate if someone can recommend me a good software tool for curve visualization
thanks

PS. One of the equations I need to visualize is the following: 
(1-(1/5000000000000000)*x-(1/5000000000000000)*y-2*x^2+(1/5000000000000000)*x^3-(1/10000000000)*y^6+x^4-(1/10000000000000000)*y^5-(1/10000000000000000)*x^5+y^4-(1/10000000000)*x^6+(1/5000000000000000)*y^3-2*y^2+(1/1666666666666666)*x*y^2+(1/1666666666666666)*x^2*y+10*y^2*x^2-4*x*y+(5999999/1000000)*x*y^3+(5999999/1000000)*x^3*y+6*y^4*x^4+(3999999/1000000)*y^5*x^3+(499999/500000)*y^6*x^2-(3999999/500000)*y^4*x^2-(999999/500000)*y^5*x-(1/3333334444444814)*y^4*x-(1/1000000)*y^7*x+(3999999/1000000)*x^5*y^3-12*x^3*y^3-(1/2500000625000156)*x^2*y^3+(499999/500000)*y^2*x^6-(3999999/500000)*y^2*x^4-(1/2500000625000156)*y^2*x^3-(999999/500000)*x^5*y-(1/3333334444444814)*x^4*y-(1/1000000)*x^7*y)=0

Comment: Have you tried SAGE?

Comment: Even better: check out [GrafEq](http://peda.com/grafeq/).

Comment: You can improve Maple's output if you use `numpoints=20000`, for example.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. I need to vizualise some "degenerate" algebraic curve which should look like two crossing lines ending abruptly. I just tried GrafEq on this equation and it hangs somewhere with Graph (82%). For implicit plot I tried up to numpoints=100000 and resolution=600 but it still does not produce any adequate image

Comment: Yes, and it's also freely available on the Internet: www.sagemath.org.

Comment: I also tried SAGE 5.0.1 implicit_plot() with plot_points=2000 for the above equation and window (-2;2)x(-2;2). There is already some contour which resembles the curve but it still too bad quality for a presentation..

Comment: if you look at the even degree stuff in x, it is a cool graph

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what type of work do you do that requires presentations on algebraic curves (if you don't mind my asking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out our xAlci curve renderer at: http://exacus.mpi-inf.mpg.de/cgi-bin/xalci.cgi. It has Flash interface and provides geometrically-correct rasterization of algebraic curves (i.e. guarantees a fixed Hausdorff distance).
You can also save computed images in png format.

I took the liberty to visualize the equation you provided:

[image]

If you zoom in at one of the self-intersection points, you will see that 
each branch is composed of a pair of curve arcs:

[image]

Comment: this looks great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grapher is good:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher
- http://guides.macrumors.com/Grapher

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I do not have Mac OS system